# Ошибки приложения при переносе на удаленный сервер

Tags: php, yii, debian

Есть веб-приложение на *Yii 1.1* - работает на локальном сервере. При переносе на удаленный сервер (работает под *Debian*) возникает ошибка 500 и соответственно ничего не работает. Ошибка в *application.log*:

> 2015/09/28 11:02:43 [error] [php] Undefined offset: 3 (/var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/protected/models/tools/Salary/ToolSalaryForm.php:258)
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(3652): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
>   #1 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(3637): ToolSalaryController->runAction()
>   #2 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(3627): ToolSalaryController->runActionWithFilters()
>   #3 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/protected/controllers/ToolController.php(42): ToolSalaryController->run()
>   #4 unknown(0): ToolController->actionProcess()
>   #5 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(4121): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()
>   #6 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(4138): CInlineAction->runWithParamsInternal()
>   #7 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(3652): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
>   #8 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(6895): ToolController->runAction()
>   #9 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(6904): CFilterChain->run()
>   #10 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(4030): CAccessControlFilter->filter()
>   #11 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(6937): ToolController->filterAccessControl()
>   #12 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(6892): CInlineFilter->filter()
>   #13 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(3642): CFilterChain->run()
>   #14 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(3627): ToolController->runActionWithFilters()
>   #15 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(1761): ToolController->run()
>   #16 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(1681): CWebApplication->runController()
>   #17 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/framework/yiilite.php(1202): CWebApplication->processRequest()
>   #18 /var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/index.php(25): CWebApplication->run()
>   REQUEST_URI=/Tool/Salary/index

`access.log` такое выдает:

> x.x.x.x - - [28/Sep/2015:11:02:43 +0900] "POST /Tool/Salary/index HTTP/1.0" 500 3312 "http://subdomain.domain.ru/Tool/Salary/index" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36"

Код `ToolSalaryForm` с 251 строчки:

```
public function validateInstitutionList($attr) {

  if ($this->institutionAll == self::INSTITUTION_CHOOSE) {

    if (!$this->institutions || (count($this->institutions) == 1 && isset($this->institutions['all']))) {

      $this->addError($attr, 'Выберете учреждения');

    }

  }

}
```

Сразу оговорюсь - не писал это приложение и не знаю, что там и как работает. Не могу понять, почему на локалке нормально отрабатывает, а на удаленном не работает. Додумался, что конфиг у сервера не такой какой-то.

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Ну так посмотрите что находится в файле `/var/www/clients/client205/web763/web/protected/models/tools/Salary/ToolSalaryForm.php` на 258 строчке и почему там может быть `Undefined offset: 3`

Comment: Вы прямо на сервере смотрите? Или где-то у себя? Надо смотреть на сервере, переходите на 258 строчку и на всякий случай переходите в конец строки (а то мало ли). Если строка нормальная, попробуйте для каждого условия выделить свою строчку и переменную, тогда будет ясно на что именно ругается. Сейчас же у вас ругается на пустую строчку (смотрел по http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814866), что не может быть правдой. И лучше часть кода перенести в вопрос, в комменте ему не место

Comment: @BOPOH предлагаете оператор if разбить на несколько?
А что тогда может быть правдой, если он реально ругается на пустую строку?)

Comment: Предлагаю сделать `$a = 1== 2; $b = 2 == 3; if (a || b) {...}`, только чтобы   каждая операция была на отдельной строчке (в условии можно все вместе хранить, мы не условие отлаживаем). Но еще раз - 258 строчка - пустая, т.е. проблема скорее всего не в этом коде. Смотрите на сервере

Comment: @BOPOH это и взято с сервера. На локалке смысла нет брать - там просто нет ошибок - всё работает)

Comment: тогда может быть файловый кэш (т.е. берет не файл на диске, а старый файл из кэша). И вы пытались перейти в конец 258 строки? Там может за пределами окна куча кода написана.

Comment: @BOPOH теперь ругается на 517 строку, хотя 258 я не трогал и сервер не дергал сутки. Там такое 
if (!$dataPeriod = $periods[$institution->id]) { так же говорит Undefined offset: 3. Причем допустим если я выберу институт с ид 85, то будет offset 85.
Плюс почему-то не работает дебагер фреймворковский =/

Comment: Вот и нашли проблему: ругается на ту же строчку, все-таки кэш был. Выведите ваш `$periods` и увидите, что там нет id институтов, там что-то другое, что только вы можете сказать. Но увидев что хранится внутри, у вас все вопросы отпадут. Т.е. у вас просто какая-то проблема в логике программы, какой должна быть логика только вы можете сказать

Comment: @BOPOH и я не могу сказать - не я писал программу. Я тоже думаю, что там что-то не то. НО ПОЧЕМУ на локальном сервере то работает?)) То ли  я дурак, то ли лыжи сломал) Как ввывести переменную? print_r не помогает)))